# How to check the textFiled input string when user inputting

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitextfield

I have a problem. 
I have four textfields, but I don't know how to check the textfield that input String.

- `nameField` doesn't over 10 strings
- `ageField` check whether is number or not
- `sexField` check male or female

This is my code:

```
- (IBAction)addComment:(id)sender {

    UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Commend" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Please input your name:";
    }];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Please input your age:";
    }];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Please input your sex:";
    }];
    [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
        textField.placeholder = @"Please input your commend:";
    }];

    UIAlertAction *sendAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"send" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action) {

        UITextField *nameField = alertController.textFields[0];
        UITextField *ageField = alertController.textFields[1];
        UITextField *sexField = alertController.textFields[2];
        UITextField *commentField = alertController.textFields[3];


        UIAlertController *successAlertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"Success" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

            [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

        }];
        [successAlertController addAction:okAction];
        [self presentViewController:successAlertController animated:YES completion:nil];


    }];

    [alertController addAction:sendAction];
    [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: you want to check while input whether correct data is being entered or not? Or after the send button is pressed?

Comment: how do you check its male or female

Comment: Why u r not using picker for age and gender field ????

Comment: I want to check while input ending and go to next textfield

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below steps, may it help:

1. Set `delegate` and `tag` to `UIAlertController` textfields.
2. Now use `UITextField` delegate method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` to validate text while typing OR use `textFieldDidEndEditing` to check after textfield end editing . Check using it's tag to differentiate between textFields.

Like,

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if(textField.tag==TxtNameTag){

   //Validate Name textField
}
//Same way for other textFields


    return YES; 
}
```

OR Use `textFieldDidEndEditing` to validate while textField end editing.

Comment: Thanks! Help me a lot.

Comment: Great :) @imbeginner_sorry

Answer (score 0):

Try textField delegate method shouldChangeCharactersInRange

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {


// here you can get your textfield text and perform an action according to your choice while user is inputting.

    return YES; //this make iOS not to perform any action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on `textField delegate` method `shouldChangeCharactersInRange`. It will get called every time when you press any character in `textfield`.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `UITextFieldDelegate`:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
```

[Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)

Answer (score 0):

plz use the the tag propertiy of textfield

```
UITextField *nameField = alertController.textFields[0];
    UITextField *ageField = alertController.textFields[1];
    UITextField *sexField = alertController.textFields[2];
    UITextField *commentField = alertController.textFields[3];


  nameField.tag = 1;
  ageField.tag = 2;

    - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    // identify with tag

   if(textField.tag == 1)
   {

   }
    else if (textField.tag == 2)
  {

  }
        return YES; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Set Delegate for UITextField.

2.Add tag.

```
UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Commend" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        [alertController addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) {
            textField.placeholder = @"Please input your name:";
            textField.tag=100;
        }];
```

3. The below Delegate will be called for every char entered.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string 
{

    if(textField.tag==100){

       //Validate Name textField
    }
    else if(textField.tag==101){
    //nextfield textFields
    }
        return YES; 
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<your text field>.delegate = self
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
   //name text field validation
   if textField == nameField{
        if textField.text.characters.count < 10 {
           return true
        }
   }

   //age text field validation
   if textField == ageField{
        if Int(textField.text) != nil {
           return true
        }
   }

   //sex text field validation
   if textField == sexField{
        if textField.text + replacementString == "male" {
              <he is a man>
        }else if textField.text + replacementString == "female"{
              <she is a woman>
        }

        return true

   }



   return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(textDidChanged:)     forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

like this copy also can check

Answer (score 0):

Try using [JSInputField](https://github.com/sspbond007/JSUIComponents/blob/master/JSKit/UIComponents/JSInputField.h) with modalViewController

```
JSInputField *inputField = [[JSInputField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:inputField];
[inputField setPlaceholder:@"Please input your name"];
[inputField setRoundedCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners];
[inputField addValidationRule:JSCreateRuleNotNullValue]; //This will validate field for null value. It will show error if field is empty.
[inputField addValidationRule:JSCreateRuleLength(10)];  //This will validate field for string of length equal to or less than 10.


JSInputField *inputField = [[JSInputField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:inputField];
[inputField setPlaceholder:@"Please input your age"];
[inputField setRoundedCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners];
[inputField addValidationRule:JSCreateRuleNotNullValue]; //This will validate field for null value. It will show error if field is empty.
[inputField addValidationRule:JSCreateRuleNumeric(0)];  //This will validate field for numeric values and restrict to enter value upto 0 decimal places.
```