# shouldChangeCharactersInRange is not getting called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, uialertcontroller

I have a textfield in the alertview called phoeNumberTF.

```
phoneNumberTF.delegate = self;

UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter your phone number" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

[alert addAction:[UIAlertAction
                  actionWithTitle:@"Send"
                  style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                  handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                  {
                      NSArray * textfields = alert.textFields;
                      phoneNumberTF = textfields[0];
                      [self sendPhoneNumber:phoneNumberTF.text];
                  }]];
```

`shouldChangeCharactersInRange` delegate method is not getting called

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{

}
```

Comment: No, you do not have a text field in the alert controller. `phoneNumberTF` has nothing to do with the alert.

Comment: then why it does not work?

Comment: The code you have posted does not add a text field to the alert controller. Is there more code you are not showing?

Comment: @rmaddy if he doesn't have text field, he will got crash when using `phoneNumberTF = textfields[0];` not only the method isn't called. Maybe he add textField but didn't write it on the question. If you give my answer down vote, consider your decision

Comment: @rmaddy Understood and removed my answer. Thank you.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39246989/how-to-check-the-textfiled-input-string-when-user-inputting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`phoneNumberTF` is not a part of `UIAlertController` so no need of delegate for this `phoneNumberTF.delegate = self;`

add the configuration delegate to your `UIAlertController`

```
 UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Enter your phone number" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];


[alert addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler:^(UITextField *textField) 
{

textField.delegate = self;
}];
```

for more info you get the sample [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32298679/enable-uialertaction-of-uialertcontroller-only-after-input)

Comment: You should mention that `phoneNumberTF` is not part of the alert and is not needed.